# Angular Httpclient PUT set boolean and body in parameters

Tags: angular, rest, parameters

I have an API Put Request.
How can I pass a model

[image]

concurrent with a boolean value

Comment: which backend technology do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image says that it is query parameter.
You need to pass that param as a part of URL itself.

See sample here.

```
https://BASE_URL/edit-bank-card?<param-name>=value
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `edit-bank-card` is a query parameter. So you could try the following

```js
editBankCard(ifEditBankCard: boolean, editOptions: any): any {
  const url = 'http://example.com/example-edit-card/?edit-bank-card=' + ifEditBankCard;
  const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  return this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(editOptions), options);
}
```

Then it can be called as

```js
const options = {
  "address": "Sample address",
  "bankCard": {
    "active": true,
    "bankName": "Sample bank",
    "cardNumber": "1234 5678 9012 3456",
  .
  .
  .
}

this.editBankCard(true, options).subscribe(
  response => { // handle response },
  error => { // handle error }
);
```